# listview cannot add or insert the item in more than one place foreach

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to add an item to my listview but I've got this Exception: Cannot add or insert the item '0' in more than one place.

The expected result is the added item but real result is this exception and I can't add an item to my listview.

My code works of this way:

First, I'm declaring the namespace and my class Takenshows.cs

```
namespace MainLayer
{
public partial class Takenshows : Form
{

    int c;
    int f;
    int d = 0;

    public List<Show> myShows;
    private ListViewColumnSorter lvwColumnSorter;
    Main p;
```

so my constructor method works - I have really more than one constructor -

```
    public Takenshows()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
        this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter;
        myShows = new List<Show>();

    }


    public Takenshows(IEnumerable<Show> shows) : this()
    {

        AddShows(shows);

    }
```

The next ones methods can receive one show from Main.cs (When I take a show pressing on taken shows button) and fill the listview from Takenshows.cs

```
internal void AddShow(Show item) => AddShows(new[] { item });

    internal void AddShows(IEnumerable<Show> items)
    {

        var lvis = items.Select(x => new ListViewItem(new[]
      {
        x.OrdNum.ToString(),
        x.DTshow.ToString(),
        x.values.ToString(),
        x.practiseNumber.ToString()
    }));

        listView1.Items.AddRange(lvis.ToArray());

    }
```

this is the method for empty listview:

```
 internal void emptyShows()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
    }
```

the method for receive shows from the listview:

```
public List<Show> getShows(List<Show> items)
    {

        return items;
    }
```

this is the Takenshows_Load

```
private void Takenshows_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // set view mode to see columns
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        listView1.Columns.Add("Order Number", 115, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Practise datetime", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("values", 420, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Practise number", 105, HorizontalAlignment.Left);


        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            int index = listView1.Items.IndexOf(item);
            item.Tag = index;
            item.Text = index.ToString();
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[0].Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[1].Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[2].Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[3].Text);
            listView1.Items.Add(item); //THIS LINE gets THE ISSUE cannot add the item '0' in more than one place
        }
        myShows = listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(lvi => (Show)lvi.Tag).ToList();

   

        for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            c = c + 1;
            listView1.Items[j].SubItems[0].Text = c.ToString();

        }

        f = Int32.Parse(c.ToString());

        var frm3 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Principal>().First();

        if (frm3 != null)
        {
            frm3.devCont();
            frm3.devcontlist(f);
            frm3.devMed(myShows);
        }

    }
```

This is the listview1_SelectedIndexChanged, on this method, the listview updates automatically.

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.BeginUpdate();
        listView1.EndUpdate();
        listView1.Invalidate();
        listView1.Update();


    }
```

Inside Takenshows.cs class when I'm removing one element pressing on delete show button happens following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        c = 0;

        if (listView1.SelectedItems != null)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
                {

                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove the selected item?", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);


                    switch (dr)
                    {
                        case DialogResult.Yes:


                            listView1.Items[i].Remove();


                            i--;

                            for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items.Count; j++)
                            {
                                c = c + 1;
                                listView1.Items[j].SubItems[0].Text = c.ToString();

                            }

                            f = Int32.Parse(c.ToString());

                            myShows = listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(lvi => (Show)lvi.Tag).ToList();

                            var frm2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Principal>().First();

                            if (frm2 != null)
                            {
                                frm2.devCont();
                                frm2.devcontlist(f);
                                frm2.devMed(myShows);
                            }

                            break;
                        case DialogResult.No:
                            break;

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

In this method, the listview sorts programatically by first column inside Takenshows.cs

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Column == 0)
        {
            if (lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn == 0)
            {
                {
                    lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
                    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
                }
            }
        }

        this.listView1.Sort();

    }
  }
}
```

And finally, inside Main.cs this is the code of the take show button when I take a show:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string values = textBox_F.Text + " " + textBox_PT.Text + " " + textBox_QT.Text + " "
    + textBox_ST.Text + " " + textBox_FPT.Text;

c = c + 1;

watchedShow = new Show
 {

    OrdNum = c + d,
    DTShow = DateTime.Now,
    Values = values,
    practiseNumber = GetPractiseNumberLN.getInstance().getPractiseNum()

 };
watchedShows.Add(watchedShow);

var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Takenshows>().FirstOrDefault();

if (frm == null)
 {

    frm = new Takenshows(watchedShows);
    frm.Show();
 }
else
 {
    frm.AddShow(watchedShow);
    frm.Activate();
 }
}
```

This line inside Takenshows.cs on Takenshows_load generates the error:

```
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Also item is an iterator which it's inside foreach loop.

I don't know how can I solve this issue. Is there any way that I can fix this issue? Probably list view doesn't update after adding or removing an element to listview.

I tried to replacing foreach loop by for loop on Takenshows_Load:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            //    int index = listView1.Items.IndexOf(i);
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Tag = i;
            item.Text = i.ToString();
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);

        }
```

But in evidence it happens nothing. How can I fix this issue? I really need fix this issue, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a foreach loop on a connection and you are adding items to the same in the loop, try replacing it with a for loop

Comment: How can I fix that? Do you have the code you refer to replacing it with a for loop to?

Comment: So, could it be that the exception tells you precisely what you do wrong, ie add an item that is already in the LV? To add several items create a fresh one each time! Note that items created in a loop would go out of scope if they could, but will not after adding them to the LV..

Comment: I'll try to replacing foreach loop by for loop. I'll see if iworks.

Comment: I've just end to edit my post (at the end of this post it's the code, the for loop with I replaced the foreach loop but nothing occurs) With the for loop, when I click on take show button, none code not executes.

Comment: You really need to use the debugger to see what exactly is going on. LV should refresh by itself but you can alsways call a Refresh() to make sure. Your new code seems to duplicate all existing rows with their values; is it running? Does the listView1.Items.Count double after?

Comment: subprocess ends with code '0'. That's the output when I execute the take show button using for loop instead of foreach loop on Takenshows_Load method.

Comment: I did that you said. I run the code. listview1.Items.Count isn't double after that and the subprocesses end with code '0' after I just pressed on take show button inside Main.cs

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
           int index = listView1.Items.IndexOf(item);
           item.Tag = index;
           item.Text = index.ToString();
           item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[0].Text);
}
```

The problem is that you are taking item and try to insert again to the same listview, this don't work. Try to create a new listviewitem.

Write me if you need more simpler sample, for example:

```
string[] row = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };
     var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row); 
     listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

this is a fast way to create a listviewitem.

Comment: I believe that I need more simpler sample. I need to add an item to listview. The listview must refresh for itself, The item I need to add to listviewitem is not a string type. It's an object type, The object's datum type is Show. This object datum type is: Show: { OrdNum: int, DTShow: Datetime, values: string, practiseNumber: int}

Comment: I think you can try object[] row = {...} instead and try to add the item after that. Even you can create the item with void data and after that fill the rest of the columns data.

Comment: and where are the attributes from the object? please read the code on AddShow and AddShows methods inside Takenshows.cs on this post. The attributes are loaded in those methods. All I need is when I'm removing one item from the listview, it refreshes for itself but it doesn't happen.